# Why does F5 on release mode re-build again all my project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, build, compilation

I work with Visual Studio 2013 and when you make changes on your code, you press F7, so it builds and then you press F5 to run/launch your program. It both works with debug and release mode.

So this is exactly the behaviour I expect from my VS project but something changed and I don't know what as I didn't change anything on the properties.

What it makes now is: you make a change, you presss F7 and it rebuilds all (until here is fine), then you press F5 and it rebuild all again! And if press F5 5 times without change the code it rebuilds 5 times! It's ilke if the project wan't up to date never

Do you know how can I stop it rebuilding if not necessary? I've check the VS properties > Build and run and everything seems fine....

Thanks in advance

Edit: I see that before rebuild it says: "Forcing recompile of all source files due to missing PDB ".\Release\vc120.pdb" so I guess I need that file but dunno why it's missing

Comment: This will be just a wild guess as long as you don't show us the trace you get when you increase the build verbosity.  Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run, don't just look at it.

Comment: @HansPassant I didnt, I tried changing options and its always the same ... what do you mean with " show us the trace you get when you increase the build verbosity. " ?? what should i show u ?

Comment: When you change the verbosity to Detailed then you get much more build information in the Output window.  It shows why it decided to build.

Comment: @HansPassant wow i didn't know that, ty so much! I see that before rebuild it says: "Forcing recompile of all source files due to missing PDB ".\Release\vc120.pdb"." maybe is because of that? i'll search what is that file.. dunno why is missing....